# Random Numbers generation

Tags: android, string, random

when i execute the code shown below

```
int random = (int)Math.ceil(Math.random()*100);
       Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), random, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

i get this log

```
E/AndroidRuntime(  994): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity Co
    mponentInfo{com.p/com.p.main}: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException:
    String resource ID #0x4b
```

Could you please tell me what is the error?

Comment: What does this have to do with random numbers?

Comment: It is related..i got my solution from one of the answers written below..

Comment: So ... not related to random numbers (as a constant number could have been used). Take time to isolate the problem -- it will pay off.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this:

```
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), Integer.toString(random), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

The Toast (or even TextViews) does not accept integers as input resources, you have to provide string resources.

Answer (score 4):

As I understand it: you've programmed your app to generate a random ID value then request the resource (i.e. a text string from the appropriate data XML files). This has very little chance of actually working unless you have a sufficient number of resources at your disposal: 0x4b == 75, so in this case it requests string with an id of 75, which you probably didn't define and hence the crash.

Yep, see also the Android documentation: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Toast.html#makeText(android.content.Context, int, int)

Answer (score 1):

well you need to type casting from integer to string

try this

```
int random = (int)Math.ceil(Math.random()*100);
       Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), ""+random, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want just display random number:

```
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), ""+random, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

If you want to display one of predefined strings just put them into array next do something like that:

```
String[] myRandomTexts = this.getResources().getStringArray(R.array.myStrings);
int random = (int)Math.ceil(Math.random()*myRandomTexts.size());
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), random, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

Answer (score 0):

The error you got appears to be unrelated to your code above, as it was caused before the above code was run. Since it's a resource not found exception for a string, I would check your layout files and such to make sure that you aren't using strings that were not created in your strings.xml.